# ReactJs Getting a styleKeeperContext' of undefined error when using Radium plugin

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

I am getting the following error :
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'styleKeeperContext' of undefined" , when i try to add a hover pseudo Class to a button that i am styling using the Radium plugin

I have tried to exclude the Radium import to see if the Rootstyle Property would still work and it did.The problem occurs whenever I add the Radium Import and export my app component Encapsulated by the Radium Function

My assumption is that the there is something i am not doing correctly either by the way i am useing the hover pseudo class , or something else , I do not understand the term 'styleKeeperContext'

how can i get rid of this error and still use The plugin , while keeping the styles scoped to my component

Screen shots of the code below

[my import statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3NJ4.png)
[my import statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/im5k0.png)

[my scoped styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnJ6F.png)

[my Component export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWY3D.png)
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4oKS.png)

Answer (score 3):

I started getting this error when I added `this.state` to a component:

```js
const MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super(); // I messed up here
    this.state = { count: 0 };
  }
  // etc.
}
```

When calling the constructor, I forgot to [pass in the component's props to `super()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class). A silly mistake to make, but the Radium error made it difficult to figure out what the root cause was.

Fixing it like this resolved the error:

```js
const MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) { // Add props argument
    super(props); // Pass props to super()
    this.state = { count: 0 };
  }
  // etc.
}
```

Comment: @madnight No problem! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue and it was resolved after lowering the Radium module version from 0.26.0 to 0.25.2.

Comment: Relevant GitHub issue: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium/issues/1042